# Get last index value from a string in SQL Server CE

Tags: sql-server-ce

I am using SQL Server Compact Edition as a database to my application.

I have a string

```
C:\wwsoftware\Application Server\3.0.000\3.0.001\IAS 3.0 P01.zip
```

I need to get the `IAS 3.0 P01.zip` value from that string.

I am able to achieve this task by using SQL Server but unable to do so in SQL Server CE.

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How have you been able to achieve this in other editions of SQL Server and what exactly happens when you try the same approach in CE?

Comment: There are a bunch of difference between CE and other editions: [Differences Between SQL Server Compact and SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140(v=sql.110).aspx), so might you be using a feature which is not supported in CE?

Comment: I am using below query for the requirement.

Comment: SELECT SUBSTRING( string , LEN(string) -  CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(string)) + 2  , LEN(string)  ) FROM SAMPLE;

Comment: another approach : SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(columnName), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(columnName)) - 1))
FROM   tableName

Comment: but sqlserver ce does't support reverse function.  So i am unable to do this task.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include such important information, don't bury it in comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

*3N1GM4* has already asked you to clarify the approach you're using successfully in SQL Server and I second that, you've not shared that information nor any detail of why that isn't working.

I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that you're using the REVERSE() function to reverse the string and CHARINDEX() to then locate the first backslash.

Unlike SQL Server, [SQL Server Compact 4.0 does not have a REVERSE() function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174077(v=sql.110).aspx), which makes it immensely harder to extract the final backslash to get the filename.

The absence of stored procedures in SQL Server Compact means it is another avenue that cannot be used.

---

*ErikEJ* has given a good alternative which is to use the .NET Framework to do the heavy lifting. If you have .NET application code that accesses the SQL Server Compact database, then you can do the extraction of the filename in the .NET code itself. I would recommend ErikEJ's approach as the best.

---

If you insist on staying within the SQL Server Compact realm, the only option purely in SQL will consist of crude hacks or "smelly" code.

**I do not advocate or support such an approach in general**, but if you wanted an indication of how to go about this, it would be something on the lines of the following SQL statement - it tries to identify the position of the backslash at the first letter, the next letter and so on, and then uses the MAX() function to find the position of the last backslash. Using that, it then extracts the filename using the SUBSTRING() function.

```
-- I do not recommend this crude approach! 
SELECT SUBSTRING(PATH, LAST_BACKSLASH + 1, LEN(PATH)) 
FROM ( 
SELECT MAX(CHARINDEX('\', PATH_QUERY.PATH, NUMBER)) as LAST_BACKSLASH, PATH_QUERY.PATH as PATH 
FROM ( 
SELECT 0 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 4 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 5 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 6 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 7 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 8 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 9 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 10 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 11 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 12 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 13 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 14 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 15 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 16 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 17 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 18 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 19 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 20 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 21 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 22 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 23 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 24 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 25 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 26 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 27 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 28 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 29 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 30 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 31 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 32 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 33 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 34 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 35 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 36 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 37 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 38 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 39 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 40 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 41 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 42 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 43 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 44 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 45 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 46 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 47 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 48 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 49 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 50 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 51 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 52 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 53 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 54 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 55 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 56 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 57 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 58 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 59 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 60 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 61 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 62 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 63 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 64 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 65 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 66 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 67 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 68 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 69 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 70 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 71 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 72 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 73 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 74 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 75 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 76 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 77 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 78 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 79 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 80 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 81 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 82 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 83 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 84 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 85 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 86 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 87 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 88 as NUMBER UNION ALL 
SELECT 89 as NUMBER           -- Best to extend this count to a larger number, like 300+ 
) AS NUMBER_LIST 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'C:\wwsoftware\Application Server\3.0.000\3.0.001\IAS 3.0 P01.zip' as PATH) as PATH_QUERY 
GROUP BY PATH_QUERY.PATH 
) as X
```

It is crude because it is a brute force approach, and it needs adapting to the maximum path length allowed (by your application and [the maximum path length of the OS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx#maxpath)).

Given SQL Server Compact is an embedded database (and not a client server database), there is no reason why you cannot do some data processing in the application code as ErikEJ has suggested. It's not as though you're cutting down the size of the result set transferred across a network.